# Escaping input for insertion into XQuery string

Tags: php, escaping, xquery, basex

Say I have the following code:

```
let $search := "placeholder"
...
...functx:get-matches-and-non-matches($t,$search)...
```

This code is stored like this in a file, gets loaded into a string (by PHP), `placeholder` gets replaced with user input, and then the code gets executed.

Obviously, `"` needs to be escaped somehow.

Is there any other stuff that needs to be escaped or removed before any user input is safe?

So far, I discovered that I need to replace `"` with `&#34;` for stuff to work, and in the process also discovered that `\` actually needs to be `&#92;&#92;` here (or `\\`, which makes it `"\\\\"` in php) and that escaping `{` and `}` might be a good idea, because they make the regex parser throw up otherwise.

Comment: Besides special characters, you should limit the scope of what can replace `placeholder`; otherwise, you're wide open for an injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't dynamically construct queries if you don't have to, you'll  have to put lots of effort into escaping to prevent code injections (and still might overlook a parameter somewhere). Consider using externally bound variables instead, which can be compared to prepared statements in SQL.

As you seem to use BaseX and PHP, this is an [example for the BaseX PHP binding](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-api/src/main/php/QueryBindExample.php):

```
// create query instance
$input = 'declare variable $name external; for $i in 1 to 10 return element { $name } { $i }';
$query = $session->query($input);
// bind variable
$query->bind("name", "number");
// print results
print $query->execute()."\n";
```

If you're using another interface to BaseX, registering external variables should be possible with all of them. Other XQuery implementations should also provide similar mechanics to bind variables, `external` variables are officially XQuery standard.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that was an option.